# forward slice in WALA IR

Tags: java, static-analysis

Is there a way to calculate a forward slice at the IR instruction-level in WALA (rather than statement level)? I'm interested in the forward slice for tainted data intra-procedurally, so I'd like the slice to consist of the IR instructions associated with that method that are affected by the originally tainted data.

I've seen plenty of references to doing something similar inter-procedurally, but cannot figure out if this is available for my purposes.

EDIT: As appropriately pointed out to me, the question should more accurately reflect what I am asking for: is this functionality already implemented in wala?

Comment: The answer to your question, "is there a way to calculate a forward slice..." is yes.  There *is* a way; implement a slicing algorithm on top of Wala.   I think you are asking if somebody has already implemented this so that you can just use it.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, sorry, I should have been more clear.  I've edited the question to reflect that. I indeed meant if there was something already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

WALA does come with a program slicer.  Here is the [slicer documentation](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Slicer).